# json conversion with gson on java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have json like following picture.

[image]

I have created 3 classes for this json.

First one is Main Class which is called KategoriResult

```
public class KategoriResult{
private String ErrorMessage;   
private String ResultCode;
private List<KategoriItem> Payload;
 ..
 ..
 getter - setter
 ..
```

Second KategoriItems

```
public class KategoriItem implements Serializable{
private int RowIdx;
private int Id;
private String Title;
private String Type;
private String WebUrl;
private List<ChildrenItem> Children;
private Boolean VideoItems;
 ..
 ..
 getter - setter
 ..
```

and ChildrenItems

```
 public class ChildrenItem implements Serializable{
private int RowIdx;
private int Id;
private String Title;
private String Type;
private String WebUrl;
private Boolean Children;
private Boolean VideoItems;
 ..
 ..
 getter - setter
 ..
```

I am trying to convert the json above to java object with gson. I am getting following error :  E/AndroidRuntime(1510): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 7729.
HOw can I fix this?

Comment: Let's see how you try to deserialize the json.

Comment: I didnt serialize json, I implemented Serializable because I will use these classes in bundle object (android)

Answer (score 0):

java:
private List ChildrenList;

json:
Children : []

May be you should rename "ChildrenList" <-> "Children". What setter name do you use?

Comment: I tried like this first. But because I got the following error I have changed it to ChildrenList : a boolean but was a bEGIN_ARRAY line 1 ..

Comment: public List<ChildrenItem> getChildrenItem() {
  return ChildrenItem;
 }
 public void setChildrenItem(List<ChildrenItem> childrenItem) {
  ChildrenItem = childrenItem;
 }

Comment: I'm confused ;)

in json you use: Children;
in java KategoriItems: private List<ChildrenItem> ChildrenList;
in java setter&getter: childrenItem

play with that name. They should be equal.

Comment: I change the name as Children I am getting following error:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a boolean but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1

Comment: May be Children isn't a issue? What about VideoItems? Is it really Boolean at KategoriItems & ChildrenItem?

Post your full json file anywhere, not image.